# Changing ymax when I use a domain in tikzpicture plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a parabola, but I want it to appear "flatter", so I was trying to increase the value of the yaxis, unfortunately, it has no effect. I think it may be due to the fact that I use domain?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Complexity}, 
ylabel={Enjoyment}, 
xticklabels={},
yticklabels={}]
    \addplot[domain=-10000:10000, black, ultra thick] {14*x - x^2};
\end{axis}
\draw[blue, ultra thick] (.4,.4) -- (4.7,.4) -- (4.7,5.44) -- (.4,5.44) -- (.4,.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Desired result (flatter curve, more space above in the plot):

[image]

I have tried putting ymax=20000 in the axis options, but it doesn't respond like normal. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try with large values `ymax=0.5E08`

Comment: You're missing the range of values you get for that domain. Turn on the `yticklabels`, and you'll see that the lowest values are around `-1e8`, so a `ymax` of 20000 isn't that much compared to the minimum. As @salimbou says, use a larger value.

Comment: Do you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given domain, the value of your function is around `-1e8` at the ends of the domain. Hence, having `ymax=2e4`, i.e. four orders of magnitude less than the absolute value of the minimum, you won't see much effect of that setting, even though it does do what it should. A larger value is needed.

Hence, `ymax=5e7` for example, will give you a flatter curve.

Comment: 5e7 probably works, also. ;-)

Comment: @JPi Ehm, yes, that's a bit easier to write.